# Set uibutton properties for a MATLAB button

Tags: matlab, button, user-interface, colors, background

I am trying to set the background color of my gui button to a different color while the program is busy doing the computation. If I just set the color to change when the button is clicked it changes; However if I add another line of code AFTER the actual computation to change the color back to it default, the color never gets changed the first time.

```
function FitData_button_Callback(hObject, ~, handles) %#ok<DEFNU>

set(handles.FitData_button,'BackgroundColor',[0 204 0]./255,'String','Fitting Data');

% do some computation that takes time here...

% this line causes the first instance of 'set' not to work
set(handles.FitData_button,'BackgroundColor',[237 237 237]./255,'String','Fit Data');
```

If I change the properties for the second time I call 'set', it does change from the default to what was specified the second time (and it does this after the long computation is finished). However, the first set of properties never get assigned.
So it seems like I am only allowed to set the BackgroundColor and String properties one time, which does not make any sence.

What gives?
thanks

Comment: I tried calling other functions and also doing a simple disp('program is here') to confirm that the comands were being called in the order they are listed.

Comment: Just confirmed that the property value is changing right after the property was set, but just the computation began.

function FitData_button_Callback(hObject, ~, handles)

set(handles.FitData_button,'BackgroundColor',[0 204 0]./255,'String','Fitting Data');
get(handles.FitData_button,'String','Fitting Data')

% do a computation that takes time here...

% --do not reset default button properties. At this point property changes from above are actually made visible.

So the property value is changing when it should, it is just not being made visible until after the computation is done running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to put a "drawnow" in the middle of your computations. The long answer is best illustrated by Yair Altman on his blog (which is FANTASTIC by the way) - http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt/